# Where can I find all Android built in themes

Tags: android, themes

At the moment im using:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Which I'm growing a bit bored of, Is there a link you can direct me to that shows me examples of all the inbuilt themes and their names?

I read on another post that there is quite a few so it would be best if there was a website/other source that could show me some previews :)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see all the theme names in the `manifest.xml`. For this see the following snapshot:[image]

Answer (score 14):

Your IDE (I know Android Studio does), should show you them.

Otherwise, here they are in raw xml form. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

More information on Android Dev docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Should be the accepted answer; doesn't assume which IDE I'm using

Comment: For newer ones: Besides themes.xml, there is also themes_holo.xml (since API 11) and themes_material.xml (since API 21). You can adjust the link above accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has a [Theme Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor.html) which provides preview function.

User can find all built-in themes inside.

2 ways to open it:

1. Open a styles XML file, for instance **res/values/styles.xml**. Then click **Open editor** near the top-right of file-editing window.
2. in top menu bar **Tools-Android-Theme Editor**.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty noobish with it all but basically I think there are only two themes. Day/Night and Light. You can select individual parts and change them but as far as I can tell there are only two themes.

As I had a comment that said this doesn't answer the question I will add that you can use Theme.AppCompat.DayNight or Theme.AppCompat.Light in the AndroidManifest.xml or in styles.xml and edit any individual attribute but there are about a million attributes and god only knows what they all do. In my opinion it's a massive oversite by android.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24515348)

Comment: Well I updated the post to include more information but the simple answer to it is that android studio have done an awful job when it comes to themes.